# Tampermonkey script to detect change on HTML and go to link automatically

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to write a script to keep looking for a tag on the html and when this tag`s class changes, it automatically redirects to a URL

My situation: Look for `<i id="icone_contabilizado" class="icon-ok-circle"></i>` change to `<i id="icone_contabilizado" class="icon-ok-sign"></i>` and automatically redirect from https://ibrep.alfamaoraculo.com.br/.../rota/27#conteudo to https://ibrep.alfamaoraculo.com.br/.../rota/28#conteudo - if possible

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), but you can do it with `setInterval` as well.

```
let myTag = document.getElementById("icone_contabilizado")
setInterval(function() {
    if (myTag.classList.contains("icon-ok-sign")) {
        window.location.href = "yoururl";
    }
}, 100);
```